# Using variables to initialize regular expressions in awk

Tags: variables, design-patterns, awk, match

I want to initialize a variable with a regular expression, and then use it for pattern matching. Results do not come as expected . So for example  I have,

```
  BEGIN {
    item_code_pattern=/ITM-CD-10/ ;
   }

   $0 ~ $item_code_pattern{ print ; }
```

I see that records which do not have pattern as ITM-CD-10  are also coming in the output.
Please suggest what should be the correct boolean expression before the block.

Thanks

Comment: Read http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps and especially make sure you understand what needs to be escaped and how many times.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use a regular string:

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    item_code_pattern = "ITM-CD-10" ;
  }

  $0 ~ $item_code_pattern { print ; } 
'
```

The `/pattern/` construct checks whether `$0` matches the given pattern, so your original code is equivalent to saying:

```
item_code_pattern = $0 ~ "ITM-CD-10"
```

Since `$0` is empty in the `BEGIN` section, `item_code_pattern` is set to 0.

Answer (score 2):

You need to drop the `$` and the `/` symbols (and there's no need for a BEGIN block, just assign the variable on the command line):

```
awk '$0 ~ item_code_pattern' item_code_pattern=ITM-CD-10
```

When you use `$`, some versions of awk will emit an error while others will silently convert the variable to an integer value of 0 so that `$item_code_pattern` is exactly the same as `$0`, and the code `$0 ~ $item_code_pattern` is the tautology `$0 ~ $0`.

If you insist on using a BEGIN block, the syntax is:

```
 BEGIN { item_code_pattern="ITM-CD-10" }
 $0 ~ item_code_pattern
```

Note that `{ print }` is the default rule when no rule is given, so it is redundant.